# Class App not found error in (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to insert the remark field into the database, but it seems that it doesn't work. So instead, I get the following error.

> Class 'App\Job' not found

**Jobs.php**

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('create-job');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**JobController.php**

```
class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreateJob(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation
        $post = new Job();
        $post->remarks = $request['remarks'];

        $request->job()->save($post);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('create-job');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is called Jobs, but you want to instantiate "Job" object:)

Comment: you have a model named as jobs but you are calling App\Job in controller that is wrong call use App\Jobs; it will get

Comment: __Jobs__ != __Job__

Comment: Jobs -> Job - Still nothing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model name is Jobs.

Need to change the name of the model to `Job`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Jobs -> Job - Still nothing :(

Comment: Just got confused. I just knew that App\Jobs is the same as app\jobs.php
I thought Jobs is the Class name. Thanks!